# Variable x might not have have been initialized?

Tags: java

I am having problem with this code, i assigned a value to variable x in if block but compiler throws an error message. I don't get it why?

```
class psp
{
public static void main(String gg[])
  {
     int x, y;
     y=5;
     if(y==5)
        {
           x=5; // i have assigned a value to x
        }
     System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: The compiler isn't sure that `y` is 5

Comment: but the value of y is 5, so why compiler is not sure about that?

Comment: Well you obviously are not sure about it, or why have an `if` statement at all?

Comment: Well, i just found this code on a website and start playing with it and then this happens..

Answer (score 3):

Because    `y=5` Is executed at runtime so the compiler doesn't know the value at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

The Java compiler does *not* take into account possible values of variables when deciding whether a certain execution path will take place.  In this case, the compiler will not take into account that `y` is `5` in deciding whether the `if` condition will always be true and thus `x` will always be initialized.

The compiler will only see an `if` without an `else` and assume that there is a possibility that the `if` condition could be `false`.

You can remove this compiler error by initializing `x` outside of the `if` block or by including an `else` block and also initializing it there.

Comment: "whether a certain execution path will take place". what this means? can you please elaborate?

Comment: The compiler sees an `if` condition, and it will not assume that the `if` block will be executed.  Because it is not accounting for variable values, the compiler sees the possibility that the `if` block will not be executed, and in this case, `x` will not have been initialized when it reaches the print statement.

Comment: I got it Sir :)